# Get position of specific word

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am new in XSLT and if it is possible to get the position of a specific word? For example, I have a data like this:

```
<Data>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!</Data>
```

I want to get the position of a "brown", "over", "dog" and "!". And, store it in different output name. Like the position of **brown** is `<foo>3</foo>`, position of **over** is `<boo>6</boo>`, **dog** `<hop>9</hop>` and **!** `<po_df>10</po_df>`. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO, @user918368. You have tagged both xslt-1.0 and -2.0, so what exactly are you using? iff 2.0 then you could remove the1.0 tag

Comment: Yes, I am using v2.0. THank you

Answer (score 1):

If you were only looking for words you could use `tokenize(., '\s+|\p{P}')`

```
<xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="words" select="tokenize(., '\s+|\p{P}')"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="'brown', 'over', 'dog'">
            <matched item="{.}" at-pos="{index-of($words, .)}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

which gives

```
<Data>
   <matched item="brown" at-pos="3"/>
   <matched item="over" at-pos="6"/>
   <matched item="dog" at-pos="9"/>
</Data>
```

so it has the right positions (I am not sure where the names of the elements you posted (like `hop`) are to be taken from so I have not tried to implement that.).

As you also want to identify a punctuation character I am not sure tokenize suffices and even with analyze-string it is not straight-forward to match and collect the position. Maybe someone else has a better idea.

Comment: To add to this answer, some regex dialects have an option to split on "word boundaries" but this is something that is highly variable from one language to another so it doesn't exist in XPath, which aims to be international. If you can come up with a solid definition of what you mean by a "word", then we can probably help you implement that definition in code.

Comment: Nice tokenize expression.